# ADAS_ATTRIB attributes available in Freemium account?

Tags: here-api

I'm playing a little with the route matching function of here api i stumbled across ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn layers, whose attributes, especially HPX, HPY and HPZ, sound pretty interesting.

Based on on the descriptions of the products on the HERE website i got the impression that these information are only accessible under the automotive product HD live maps: "Access high-definition, lane-level information to enable latitudinal and longitudinal control and precise localisation of a vehicle." In particular when querying the mapping from layers to feature packages as described here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/example-layers.html, i found that the ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn layers belong to the feature "PDE-Premium-Adas".

However, when i extend a route matching query, asking for inclusion of these attributes for all route links (by appending "&attributes=ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn(*)") to the query, the response includes all attributes of the ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn layers for each route link.

My question is: Is it intended by HERE that attributes from these layers are accessible using only a Freemium account, or is this by accident?

The reason i am asking is that i do not want to get into a legal problem by using this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn is accessible by freemium account. PDE-Premium-Adas feature states that the content is a premium content(special sources, etc) and not whether it is accessible by freemium or not. Freemium account only has a transaction limit per month post which you wont be able to access the information. Other than that you are allowed to query this data. One thing to remember is you should not store the information you get from our APIs in your database. You can also read the terms and conditions on developer site to know more. Hope this helps!